# How to find in a column when the row at time t is different from the one at t-1?

Tags: r, dataframe

I  have a dataframe with 3 columns. For each column I would like to get when the jth row of column i is different from its past value. Ideally I would like to get the dates when this change happens.

Let me take an example to clarity what I mean. This is my dataframe:

```
df = structure(list(Date = c("2005-11-30", "2005-12-31", "2006-01-31", 
"2006-02-28", "2006-03-31", "2006-04-30", "2006-05-31", "2006-06-30", 
"2006-07-31", "2006-08-31", "2006-09-30", "2006-10-31", "2006-11-30", 
"2006-12-31", "2007-01-31", "2007-02-28", "2007-03-31", "2007-04-30", 
"2007-05-31", "2007-06-30"), MLF = c(3, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.5, 
3.5, 3.5, 3.75, 3.75, 4, 4, 4.25, 4.25, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.75, 
4.75, 4.75, 5), MRO = c(2, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.75, 
2.75, 3, 3, 3.25, 3.25, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 4), 
    DFR = c(1, 1.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.75, 1.75, 2, 
    2, 2.25, 2.25, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.75, 2.75, 2.75, 3)), row.names = 83:102, class = "data.frame")

          Date  MLF  MRO  DFR
83  2005-11-30 3.00 2.00 1.00
84  2005-12-31 3.25 2.25 1.25
85  2006-01-31 3.25 2.25 1.25
86  2006-02-28 3.25 2.25 1.25
87  2006-03-31 3.50 2.50 1.50
88  2006-04-30 3.50 2.50 1.50
89  2006-05-31 3.50 2.50 1.50
90  2006-06-30 3.75 2.75 1.75
91  2006-07-31 3.75 2.75 1.75
92  2006-08-31 4.00 3.00 2.00
93  2006-09-30 4.00 3.00 2.00
94  2006-10-31 4.25 3.25 2.25
95  2006-11-30 4.25 3.25 2.25
96  2006-12-31 4.50 3.50 2.50
97  2007-01-31 4.50 3.50 2.50
98  2007-02-28 4.50 3.50 2.50
99  2007-03-31 4.75 3.75 2.75
100 2007-04-30 4.75 3.75 2.75
101 2007-05-31 4.75 3.75 2.75
102 2007-06-30 5.00 4.00 3.00
```

For each column now, I would like to have a code that tells me, for example, that `2005-12-31 3.25 2.25 1.25` differs from its previous values. I would like to do this for the entire dataframe and for each column.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag` to compare values from it's previous values.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  filter(MLF != lag(MLF) & MRO != lag(MRO) & DFR != lag(DFR))

#        Date  MLF  MRO  DFR
#1 2005-12-31 3.25 2.25 1.25
#2 2006-03-31 3.50 2.50 1.50
#3 2006-06-30 3.75 2.75 1.75
#4 2006-08-31 4.00 3.00 2.00
#5 2006-10-31 4.25 3.25 2.25
#6 2006-12-31 4.50 3.50 2.50
#7 2007-03-31 4.75 3.75 2.75
#8 2007-06-30 5.00 4.00 3.00
```

In `data.table`, we can use `shift` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[MLF != shift(MLF) & MRO != shift(MRO) & DFR != shift(DFR)]
```

Comment: super nice! thanks a lot, super helpful!